# Multiple button styles in a theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I want to be able to dynamically change the theme of my app based on a flag sent from the server. In order to do this I have a default theme and an alternate theme. The problem is I have multiple button styles implemented in my app. Each of these button styles will now have an alternate style to fit in with the alternate theme. Is there a way to declare multiple button styles in a theme or will I have to create custom Button widgets that use custom style attributes?

Thanks

Comment: did you ever find the answer?